# Generate random date greater than current date using JAVA

Tags: java, date, calendar, do-while

I want to generate a random date (`date2`) which should be greater than current date (`date1`) using JAVA

In order to achieve this, I tried following do-while loop but it does not run properly.

How can I get this working? or is there a better way to get the desired results?

*P.S. not so good in JAVA, so any support is highly appreciated!*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    do {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(""+String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-"+String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))+"-"+String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DATE))+"");       
        Date date2 = sdf.parse(""+String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))+"-"+createRandomIntBetween(1, 12)+"-"+createRandomIntBetween(1, 28)+"");
        
    }
    
    while (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0);
    
}

public static int createRandomIntBetween(int start, int end) {
            return start + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start));
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, *why* would you want to create a greater date, because currently you only use it in the `do`-`while` loop. Please clarify

Comment: Why not just add a random number of days to the current date using the existing methods of the calendar class? eG `c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, new Random().nextInt(365))`

Comment: @Lino Pardon, but this is how I initially tried to get the results. Not good in Java :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution will generate a random date from tomorrow and a year forward

```
Random randomDays = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(randomDays.nextInt(365) + 1);
```

Depending on the range of the date you want you can of course change the *bound* parameter to `nextInt`.

Comment: Instead of using `new Random()` you could also use  `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`

Comment: @Lino thanks for the suggestion, added it to my answer since it's an improvement

Answer (score 1):

Date and Time is simply a int in java, we can simple use the idea of generating random int to generate date between 2 dates.

```
public static Date randomDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    long startMillis = startDate.getTime();
    long endMillis = endDate.getTime();
    long randomMillis = ThreadLocalRandom
      .current()
      .nextLong(startMillis, endMillis);

    return new Date(randomMillis);
}
```

Comment: if you want to generate the date from today to next year then you can simply do this 
long startMillis = todayDate.getTime();
  
     long randomMillisSinceEpoch = ThreadLocalRandom
       .current()
       .nextLong(startMillis, startMillis+(365*24*60*60*1000));

     System.out.println(new Date(randomMillisSinceEpoch));